# Keyboard macro cycling over a list of entries and inserting

Tags: emacs

I was learning about keyboard macros and counters which are awesome. For example, you can increment a counter within your keyboard macro with `C-x C-k C-i`.

Is it possible to cycle over a list? For example, let's say I have this list: `("oranges" "apples" "bananas")`
How can I edit the following text

```
Monday, I eat
Tuesday, I eat
Wednesday, I eat
```

To look like this?

```
Monday, I eat oranges
Tuesday, I eat apples
Wednesday, I eat bananas
```

Arriving at the end of the list, the next execution of the keyboard macro would cycle back to the beginning. How can I do this with keyboard macros? Are keyboard macros the best way?

Comment: I'd put the list of items somewhere suitable into the buffer and in my macro jump to the correct position, cut the text, jump back and yank it. (Self-plug: detour.el would help me with this.)

Comment: You can, of course, use multiple buffers.  It's usually easier to switch buffers back and forth (each with their own persistent point) than it is to jump to and from different blocks of text within a single buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume we have a buffer with the following contents:

```
Monday, I eat
Tuesday, I eat
Wednesday, I eat
Thursday, I eat
Friday, I eat
Saturday, I eat
Sunday, I eat
```

Also assume we have our choices in a list, let's call it `my-snacks`:

```
(setq my-snacks '("oranges" "apples" "bananas"))
```

To use a counter to iterate repeatedly over the `my-snacks` list, we can use an index value formed from the remainder of dividing the value of the keyboard macro counter by the length of the list:

```
(nth (% MACRO-COUNTER-VALUE (length my-snacks)) my-snacks)
```

Our keyboard macro can use `eval-expression` to insert the value of the list indexing operation.

We start with point at the beginning of the buffer. The keyboard macro performs the following steps:

1. Go to end of line: <kbd>C-e</kbd>
2. Insert a space: <kbd>SPC</kbd>
3. Eval expression: <kbd>M-:</kbd>
4. Insert the portion of the above elisp expression that precedes the insertion of the keyboard counter value: <kbd>(insert (nth (%</kbd>
5. Insert the keyboard macro counter value: <kbd>F3</kbd>
6. Insert the rest of the elisp expression:  <kbd>(length my-snacks)) my-snacks))</kbd>
7. Hit enter: <kbd>RET</kbd>
8. Go to the beginning of the line: <kbd>C-a</kbd>
9. Go to the next line: <kbd>C-n</kbd>

As indicated in the [keyboard macro counter documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macro-Counter.html#Keyboard-Macro-Counter), the keyboard macro uses the <kbd>F3</kbd> key to insert the current value of the keyboard macro counter.

Here's the same macro in keyboard macro form:

```
C-e                 ;; move-end-of-line
SPC                 ;; self-insert-command
M-:                 ;; eval-expression
(insert             ;; self-insert-command * 7
SPC                 ;; self-insert-command
(nth                ;; self-insert-command * 4
SPC                 ;; self-insert-command
(%                  ;; self-insert-command * 2
SPC                 ;; self-insert-command
<f3>                ;; kmacro-start-macro-or-insert-counter
SPC                 ;; self-insert-command
(length             ;; self-insert-command * 7
SPC                 ;; self-insert-command
my-snacks))         ;; self-insert-command * 11
SPC                 ;; self-insert-command
my-snacks))         ;; self-insert-command * 11
RET                 ;; newline
C-a                 ;; move-beginning-of-line
C-n                 ;; next-line
```